# Proof of series convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Proove that if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n a_n)^2$ 
is convergent, than the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$
is also convergent.

Comment: Could you rewrite the problem clearly, please? I can't understand!

Comment: Is $a_n$ supposed to be non negative ? What have you tried ? Where do this problem come from ?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be non negative.

Comment: I have seen a similar problem that uses the limit comparison test, but I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: You will get more help here if you show what you've tried and what are your difficulties.

Comment: I have calculated a lim of a_n/(na_n)^2. The calculated limit is 0, so it is proven that the series converges, right? Thanks.

Comment: Why does $a_n/(na_n)^2=1/(n^2a_n)$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $a_n = n a_n\times \frac{1}{n}$ and use the inequality
$$\forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2,\qquad 2xy\le x^2+y^2.$$